# Create a view of Document Sets in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-set

I have a Document Library that has folders. Inside these folders are Document Sets. I have to use BOTH folders and Document sets for a variety of reasons i won't go in to here.

I wanted to create a View that would show all the Document Sets WITHOUT the root folders. I thought I could do this using the Filter but I don't see how.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Customise your library view.  In the settings there is a section towards the bottom called Folders - here you need to select 'Show all items without folders'.

Once you have done this then you can go ahead and filter your view:

Content Type = Document Set (or whatever the name of the content type is for your document sets)

Just filtering by the content type will not show documents or document sets that are in folders.

Comment: unfortunately this just returns all documents content type items. not all "document set" content type items.

Comment: I should have clarified that you need to combine this with a filter.  I have amended my response above.

Comment: still doesn't work.  modified my question to show the images of me following the directions correctly.  no results display (the only image i'm leaving out).

Comment: Well it certainly looks like you are setting it up correctly.  I have just tested the scenario in my own environment and it worked fine so I am rather puzzled why you are not getting the expected results.

Comment: is your environment nested doc sets within folders in a doc library?

Comment: I created a couple of folders and then added Doc Sets within the folders.

Comment: shoot. i even recreated the scenario under a new library and the same results :(

Comment: Unfortunatly the content type (a doc set) in question is a container and is derived from 'folder'. If you select 'Show all items without folders' then you are hiding the very thing that you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

We believe this is impossible using Nested Document Sets in Folders. This is because the Folder content type is part-parent of the hybrid 'Document Set' content type....so when you select to show all document sets inside folders it filters OUT the document set based on the folder attribute.